# Compose a SQL query that produces monthly revenue by channel and the previous month's revenue

Tags: sql, database, pgadmin, revenue

Hey everyone I have two tables with output like this:

Month_Table

[image]

Transaction_Table
[image]

I need to calculate the monthly revenue by channel and the previous month's revenue: I did this query but it is not completed

```
Select date_created, channel, sum(revenue) as monthly_revenue 
from transaction_table  
GROUP BY  date_created,channel
```

The result should be displaying monthly revenue and the month's revenue of previous month.

How can I do that?

Comment: When the sum of each month is calculated, what is the need for the previous month's account?

Comment: It is a question in my exam, I don't see as well the reason why to display the revenue of previous month 0.0

Comment: OK . I realized . So it's a test question

Comment: yes it is a test question :D do you think there is anything I should add then to the query  ? Your answer was the perfect one between ! Great job thx

Comment: Just because your question asks for the previous month, if you can add it, your answer will be complete.

Comment: @ AhlemMustapha I also added last month's sales. See it works right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code .

```
with resultTable as(
select RT.channel,RT.sumRevenue,LT.[month-start_date],LT.month_end_date,LT.year_month
from (select t.channel,sum(revenue) as sumRevenue,M.month_index from Month_Table M,Transaction_Table T
where t.date_created BETWEEN m.[month-start_date] AND m.month_end_date
group by m.month_index,t.channel) RT Join Month_Table LT on RT.month_index = LT.month_index
)
select * from resultTable
```

output:

[image]

OR use this query

```
with resultTable as(
select RT.channel,RT.sumRevenue,LT.[month-start_date],LT.month_end_date,LT.year_month
from (select t.channel,sum(revenue) as sumRevenue,M.month_index from Month_Table M,Transaction_Table T
where t.date_created BETWEEN m.[month-start_date] AND m.month_end_date
group by m.month_index,t.channel) RT Join Month_Table LT on RT.month_index = LT.month_index
)
select *,LAG(sumRevenue,1) OVER (PARTITION BY channel ORDER BY channel) previous_month_sales from resultTable
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Very helpful too, thank you for providing me with another solution -> I did the following changes and it worked perfectly fine :) 
with resultTable as(
select RT.channel,RT.sumRevenue,LT.month_start_date,LT.month_end_date,LT.year_month
from (select t.channel,sum(revenue) as sumRevenue,M.month_index
   from month_table M,transaction_table T
where t.date_created BETWEEN m.month_start_date AND m.month_end_date
group by m.month_index,t.channel)
RT Join Month_Table LT on RT.month_index = LT.month_index
)
select * from resultTable !! I really appreciate your contribution

Comment: Great Job , SQL hero 

Answer (score 1):

You could try uing a a join  between you tables

```
Select a.month_index, a.year_month, b.channel, sum(b.revenue) as monthly_revenue 
from Month_Table a 
from transaction_table  b ON b.date_created between a.month_start_date and a.month_and_date
    amd month(b.date_created) = betwwen month(curdate()) -1 and month(curdate())
GROUP BY  a.month_index, a.year_month, b.channel
order by a.year_month desc
```

Comment: I did some changes like this and it helped me to get the monthly revenue correctly : Select 
M.month_index,
M.year_month,
T.channel,
sum(t.revenue)as monthly_revenue
from month_table M left join 
transaction_table T
on T.date_created between M.month_start_date and M.month_end_date
Group by M.month_index, M.year_month, T.channel
Order by M.year_month desc  
You are amazing man thank you :)

Comment: I have a question now how to edit that query to add the previous month revenue ? 
Another question : there are two months without any revenue so it gives me NULL values how can I exclude them ? I would appreciate your help , as I am still looking to improve my answer

Comment: is not easy understand  your request  .. .. you should update your question and based on the sample provided  you should add  the expected  result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select t1.date_created, t1.channel, sum(t1.revenue) as monthly_revenue ,sum(t2.revenue) prev_month_revenue
from transaction_table t1 left join transaction_table t2  on t1.channel = t2.channel and to_char(t1.date_created,'MM') = to_char(add_months(t2.date_created,-1),'MM')
GROUP BY  t1.date_created,t1.channel;
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is just a code? Please provide more explaination and details. You can also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  and give awesome quality answers.

Comment: Thank you Rishab !